# Searching for any images in media library displays "no media found"

Tags: images, search, media, media-library

When I try to search for images in the Wordpress backend 'media' library, the search does not work. I know this is a core WP function but it seems like something is rendering this function broken.

I've tried:

- deactivating all plugins & switching themes
- Checked the permissions for /uploads folder (set to 755 recursively).
- Wordpress is up to date (4.8.3)
- Checked PHP version (5.3.3)

Still displays `no media found`.

The current setup is running a multisite. I've combed through the code but don't see anything out of line. The inspector console  doesn't show any error messages.

I also checked the server log and it display `Unknown column wp_postmeta.meta.key`. This is the closest error I could find. The image grid displays all the photos fine and the img url links seem to be fine. Any suggestions for next steps?